# java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liferay-6, jboss6.x

We are using spring, SOLR and Oracle + hibernate in our web application.

The developer although has written some incorrect code and marked some of the methods communicating with SOLR with @Transactional annotation.

Moreover We can see in the thread dump that Threads are getting in the waiting state or in the block state while entering in these methods i.e the cause appears to be the transactional behavior of these methods

1) It seems that hibernate connection is getting created although it is not   required, which is resulting in the wait state of other threads who are expecting connection but due to limited connections available in the connection they are unable to have it,thus causing the wait/block state of the threads.

2) Moreover there could be situations where the service methods threads who have the connection from connection pool and are calling other service methods that are transactional in nature,are landing into locked state.
Which in turn are depleting connection from connection pool

let me know whether the inference is correct or not, if not can you let me know the pointers

Comment: The @ Transactional 's propagation level is Propagation.REQUIRED by default, which means that it will not open a new transaction by itself. Removing the @ Transactional works for you? If your application has a good connection pooling, I think the application should be able to give enough connections for you. I also hope that the it's container managed transaction.

Comment: You are correct on this front, but we are facing the mentioned issues ---                      1) threads are getting into wait block                                                                2) connections are not getting back to the pool                                                   somehow when we removed the @transactional block from only one of the method we saw the definite improvement                                                  can you give some places to look into in order to get the problem statement

Comment: @KarthikR Actually the default `REQUIRED` requires a transaction, and if none exist a new one is started.

Comment: Correct. I didn't add extra info. And what I'm getting at is, the Thread will can wait for connection and not the transaction by itself. If the connection was available it will readily create/use the transaction available. Edited my previous comment below to newer one

Comment: The @ Transactional 's propagation level is Propagation.REQUIRED by default, which means that it will not open a new transaction by itself unless not available. Removing the @ Transactional works for you? If your application has a good connection pooling, I think the application should be able to give enough connections for you. I also hope that the it's container managed transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's right to blame the `@Transactional` annotation or the developer who added it. It's just for your transaction management and not connection pooling.

The number of connections in the connection pool should be increased I believe.

If the methods annotated with `@Transactional` alone has the problem, and you have limited connections available, then the problem seems to be with the connection pooling mechanism you have followed. Please try increasing the number of connections available.

Comment: Thanks kartik, do you know in  case we have two transaction managers and two session factories and if I annotate one of the methods by @transactional annotate how the spring container will know which transaction manager to be provided taking into account I have already created one of the base class which injects the required session factory to be used

Comment: Yes. You can use @ Transactional("tx1") and @ Transactional("txt2") . Please see here for custom transactions http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes . Hope this helps. Please mark the answer so thread can be closed. Thanks :)